# What is the average and worst case time complexity of an n-ary tree traversal that adds tree nodes into a vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I'm struggling to understand the time complexity of this algorithm. Given an n-ary tree traversal algorithm like so:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> levelOrder(Node* root) {
  std::queue<Node*> queued_nodes;
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> return_vector;
  if (!root) {
    return return_vector;
  }
  queued_nodes.push(root);
  queued_nodes.push(nullptr);
  std::vector<int> current_vector;
  while (!queued_nodes.empty()) {
    Node* current_node = queued_nodes.front();
    queued_nodes.pop();
    if (current_node) {
      current_vector.push_back(current_node->val);
      for (Node* child : current_node->children) {
        queued_nodes.push(child);
      }
    } else {
      if (!queued_nodes.empty()) {
        queued_nodes.push(nullptr);
      }
      if (current_vector.size()) {
        return_vector.push_back(current_vector);
        current_vector.clear();
      }
    }
  }
  return return_vector;
}
```

The above algorithm does a breadth first search on a tree. `current_vector` stores a vector of nodes found on the current level of the tree. `return_vector` stores a vector of vectors for each level in the tree. Whenever we encounter a new node from the queue, we `push_back()` the node to `current_vector`, and if we start to explore a new level in the tree we `push_back()` the `current_vector` to the `return_vector` and then clear the `current_vector`.

1) I know that depth first search on a graph has a time complexity of O(V + E), and on a binary tree since there are twice as many edges as there are nodes we can generalise it to O(V). However can we make the same assumptions here on an n-ary tree?

2) I know that the time complexity of `push_back()` is an amortised constant, but we are doing it  at least |V| times (once for each `Node*` in the tree) . So how would the `push_back()` of a `Node*` to `current_vector` and `push_back()` of a `current_vector` to `return_vector` affect the time complexity of the whole algorithm?

Could anyone tell me how they would approach analysing the complexity of such an algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The number of edges in a tree is always `V-1`. You can see this by orienting each edge away from the root. Then each node has exactly one incoming edge except the root, which has none.

If `V` only counts the non-leaf nodes, this is of course not correct anymore. Then we can say that the number of edges is at most the total sum of all degrees of inner nodes, since each edge is incident to at least one inner node. (Actually, we know that `2E = sum of degrees + number of leafs`, but that's not important here). Hence, for n-ary Trees, we have `E <= N * V` since the degree of each inner node in an N-ary tree is (at most) N.

Therefore the running time of the dfs is `O( V + N * V) = O(V)` since N is constant.

2) The `push_back` on `current_vector` is called once per node. The `push_back` on `return_vector` is called once per level, which can be also bounded by V. Since the amortized running time of the method is constant, the amortized running time of all these operations is `O(V)`.

There is a problem that with the `push_back` you copy the `current_vector`, so everyone of its elements is again looked at and copied. But for each node of the tree this is only done once, hence this in `O(V)`.

So the influence is that the running time estimation is only amortized anymore.

Regarding more practical performance aspects: You should move the `current_vector` to `return_vector`. This has constant runtime and not linear in the number of elements as the copy is.